# ath9k driver sees only some Wi-fi networks

Tags: ubuntu, networking, wifi, drivers, access-point

I have PCI Wi-Fi adapter:

```
06:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
```

using ath9k driver. When I boot into Windows I can all **all** networks(including mine AP). But when I boot into Ubuntu(6.5.0-21-generic) mine AP is not visible.

I have already faced similar problem with lower kernel(5.15.0-79-generic), in that case helped to set driver parameter:

```
options ath9k nohwcrypt=1
```

but since I've upgraded to kernel 6.5 this w/o does not work anymore.
Do I need to download some firmware for this card?

Once I was able to connect to AP from Linux, when I booted 1st into Windows and then rebooted into Linux. But I was never able to reproduce it.

PS: it is not about signal strength, I put AP just next to mine PC. And Windows shows not problem with signal strength.

Comment: That chip only works with b/g/n on 2.4Ghz. Are you sure that those missing SSIDs are broadcast on within those? Secondly, do you have the latest wireless-regdb installed?

Comment: Thanks for help the problem really something to do with region database. See solution bellow

Answer (score 0):

Summary:

- `/sbin/crda` is no more part of Debian/Ubuntu installation.
- `cat /sys/module/cfg80211/parameters/ieee80211_regdom` shows region 00
- `iw reg get` shows region `00`
- `iw reg set EU` or `iw reg set CZ` wont change anything
- `iwlist wlan0 channel` shows channels 12-14 disabled
- `/etc/default/crda` is not used anymore

Solution:

```
cat > /etc/modprobe.d/cfg80211.conf <<EOF   
options cfg80211 ieee80211_regdom=CZ
EOF
reboot
```